# Ajax Fires only once and get undefined index form_build_id error

Tags: forms, ajax, commerce

What I am trying to do is update a set of select drop-downs in a wrapper on press of a submit button.I am calling an ajax callback function but it executes only once and the second time onwards it throws in this error-

> Notice: Undefined index: form_build_id in ajax_get_form() (line 320 of
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\artcheckin\includes\ajax.inc).

Any reason why this could be happening ??

EDIT- Here is the code (apologies if it looks a bit messed up cause ive been trying to debug it)

```
$form['main-table']['headc'] = array(
  '#prefix'=> '<div id="ajax-wrapper"><table class ="multiupload-main-table"><tr class="table-header">',
  '#suffix'=> '</tr></table></div>',
);

$form['main-table']['billing']['name_block']['name'] = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title'=> 'Full Name');

$form['main-table']['billing']['street_block']['thoroughfare'] = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title'=> 'Address 1');
$form['main-table']['billing']['locality_block']['locality'] = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title'=> 'City');
$form['main-table']['billing']['locality_block']['administrative_area'] = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title'=> 'State');
$form['main-table']['billing']['locality_block']['postal_code'] = array('#type' => 'textfield','#title'=> 'Pin');
$form['main-table']['billing']['shipping_details']['click_tags'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value'=> t("Submit"),
  '#name' => t('click_tags'),
  '#ajax'                      => array(
    'callback'=> 'arjun_submit',
    'wrapper' => 'ajax-wrapper',
    'effect'  => 'fade',
  ),
);


$result = db_select('bhavishya_test','f')
->fields('f', array('test'))
->execute();
$num_rows_content = $result->rowCount();
$options          = array();
for ($i = 0;$i < $num_rows_content; $i++) {
  $record = $result->fetchObject();
  $options[$i] = $record->test;
}



$form['main-table']['headc']['checkc'] = array(
  '#type'      => 'checkbox',

  '#attributes' => array('onclick'=> 'checkUncheckAll(this);'),
  '#weight'    => - 1,
  '#prefix'    => '<td>',
  '#suffix'    => '</td>',
);

$form['main-table']['headc']['selling_price'] = array(
  '#type'         => 'textfield',
  '#title'        => 'Selling Price',
  '#default_value'=> '0',
  '#size'         => 5,
  '#maxlength'    => 20,
  '#attributes'                                  => array('onclick'=> 'ac_selling_price()','onkeyup'=> 'ac_selling_price()'),
  '#prefix'       => '<td>',
  '#suffix'       => '</td>'

);
//want to update this select box !!!
$form['main-table']['headc']['select_shipping_address_head'] = array(
  '#type'      => 'select',
  '#title'=> 'width',
  '#options'   => $options,
  '#attributes' => array('onclick'=> 'applyAll(this);','onkeyup'=> 'applyAll(this);'),
  '#prefix'    => '<td>',
  '#suffix'    => '</td>',
);

for ($i = 0;$i < count($form_state['storage']['image_src']);$i++) {
  if ($form_state['storage']['sale'][$i] != 0) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
      $class = "even-row";
    }
    else      $class = "odd-row";

    $form['main-table']['sale']['start-table'.$i] = array(
      '#markup'=> '<table class="multiupload-main-table multiupload-stage-5-tables"><tr class = "'.$class.'">',
    );

    $form['main-table']['sale']['checkc'.$i] = array(
      '#type'         => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value'=> 0,
      '#prefix'       => '<td>',
      '#suffix'       => '</td>',
    );
    $form['main-table']['sale']['img'.$i] = array(
      '#prefix'=>'<td><div style="width:100px;height:100px;">',
      '#markup'=>'<img src="'.$form_state['storage']['image_src'][$i].'" alt="llopp">',
      '#suffix'=>'</div></td>',
    );

    $form['main-table']['sale']['check_selling_price'.$i] = array(
      '#type'  => 'checkbox',
      '#title' =>'Buy Now',
      '#prefix'=> '<td>',
    );
    $form['main-table']['sale']['quote_Allow'.$i] = array(
      '#type'  => 'checkbox',
      '#title' =>' Make Offer',
      '#suffix'=> '</td>',
    );

    $form['main-table']['sale']['selling_price'.$i] = array(
      '#type'         => 'textfield',
      '#title'        => 'Price',
      '#default_value'=> '0',
      '#size'         => 5,
      '#maxlength'    => 20,
      '#prefix'       => '<td>',
    );


    $form['main-table']['sale']['quoteAllow'.$i] = array(
      '#type'         => 'textfield',
      '#title'        => 'Icon',
      '#default_value'=> '0',
      '#size'         => 5,
      '#maxlength'    => 20,
      '#suffix'       => '</td>',
      '#states'                                                                              => array(
        'enabled' => array(
          ':input[name="quote_Allow'.$i.'"]' => array("checked"=> TRUE),
        ),
      ),
      '#attribute'                                             => array('disabled'=> 'disabled'),
    );
    //want to update this select box !!!
    $form['main-table']['sale']['select_shipping_address'.$i] = array(
      '#type'   => 'select',
      '#title'  =>'Shipping Address',
      '#options'=> $options,
      '#prefix' => '<td>',
      '#suffix' => '</td>',
    );

    $form['main-table']['sale']['ship_def'] = array(
      '#type'  => 'fieldset',
      '#prefix'=> '<td><div id="display_shipping_address">',
      '#suffix'=> '</div></td>',
    );
    $form['main-table']['sale']['ship_def']['display'] = array(
      '#markup'=> 'markup arjun',
    );

    $form['main-table']['sale']['end-table'][$i] = array(
      '#markup'=> '</tr></table>',
    );

  } //inner if ends
} //inner for ends

if (isset($form_state['triggering_element'])) {
  if ($form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'click_tags') {
    $p     = $form_state['values']['name'];
    //insert into Database
    $query = "INSERT INTO `artcheckin`.`bhavishya_test` (`test`) VALUES ('$p');";
    $result= db_query($query);

    //Fetch all the optins again from DB
    $result= db_select('bhavishya_test','f')
    ->fields('f', array('test'))
    ->execute();
    $num_rows_content = $result->rowCount();
    $address_options  = array();
    for ($i = 0;$i < $num_rows_content; $i++) {
      $record = $result->fetchObject();
      $options[$i] = $record->test;
    }
    //assign options to the select box in headc
    $form['main-table']['headc']['select_shipping_address_head']['#options'] = $options;
    // assign all the options to the rest of the select boxes in  the DOM begining with id = "select_shipping_address"
    foreach ($form_state['values'] as $key => $value) {
      if (strpos($key,"select_shipping_address") !== false) {
        $form['main-table']['sale']["$key"]['#options'] = $options;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And My callback function is-

```
function arjun_submit( &$form, & $form_state)
{
  return $form['main-table'];
}
```

What I want in the end to achieve is that on submit of **$form['main-table']['billing']**, the dropdowns- **$form['main-table']['headc']['select_shipping_address_head']** and **$form['main-table']['sale']['select_shipping_address'.$i]** should get updated with the latest options..

Comment: Please add your code, nothing we can do without that :)

Comment: Apologies..done :)